# PHP MySQLInsert prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am working on learning about PHP prepared statements and implementing them when using the MySQL INSERT command. I am able to do this just fine without the prepared statements, but I am confused on where I went wrong in my code after adding prepared statements.

The below code gives me the "Internal Server Error", but it appears to be syntactically correct.

EDIT:

Here is dbConnet.php:

```
    <?php 

$hostname = "*";    
$username = "*";                
$database = "*";                
$password = "*";


$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);  


if (!$link)                                     
    { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());        
    }
?>
```

Code:

```
<?php
        include('dbConnect.php');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Articles (content, date) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $article, $submitTime);

$article = $_POST['articleArea'];
$submitTime = new DateTime();
$submitTimeString = $submitTime->format("m-d-Y H:i:s");

$stmt->execute();

    if (mysqli_query($link,$stmt) )
{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Article has been submitted!')</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'URL'</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Uh oh! An error has been encountered! Please try to resubmit your article.')</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'URL'</script>";
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Any insight into my issue is greatly appreciated. If you need me to add more info, please let me know!

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you initializing $link?

Comment: Look at your error logs and/or activate explicit error reporting. "Internal server error" doesn't help at all, you need detailed error messages from PHP.

Comment: I am initializing $link from dbConnect. I have updated my original question to include the code from dbConnect as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO Articles (content, date) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $article, $submitTimeString);

    $article = $_POST['articleArea'];
    $submitTime = new DateTime();
    $submitTimeString = $submitTime->format("m-d-Y H:i:s");
```

Instead of

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Articles (content, date) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $article, $submitTime);

$article = $_POST['articleArea'];
$submitTime = new DateTime();
$submitTimeString = $submitTime->format("m-d-Y H:i:s");
```

If that error is being caused by trying to connect to the database with both $link and $mysqli (as pointed out by deceze) this should fix that issue. As for the date, I would suggest changing "date" to a "text" datatype in your database (hence the `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $article, $submitTimeString);` vs `$stmt->bind_param('si', $article, $submitTimeString);`)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your database connection is `$link`, yet you use `$mysqli->prepare(..)`. Which is it?
2. You're `execute()`ing the `$stmt`, yet you also next use `mysqli_query()`. That's nonsense. Use one or the other, not both.
3. `mysqli_query()` expects a *query string*, but you're giving it a prepared statement object.
4. You're binding `$submitTime` to the statement, which is a `DateTime` object, which mysqli will likely not like. You're never using your formatted date `$submitTimeString` anywhere.

Any one of these mistakes will likely trigger the fatal error. You need to rewrite that from scratch. [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) for how to use the mysqli extension.

Answer (score 0):

is $submitTime defined at the time it is bound to $stmt?
Both $article and $submitTime are initialized after being bound.
And you should bind the date string, not the DateTime object.

Answer (score -1):

the `$submitTimeString` format is wrong.  MySQL expects datetimes as `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` (year first)

Comment: yeah, that won't break it, it just inserts '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as the date